# Excel iso 8601 timestamp subtract 2 hours convert

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datetime-format, data-migration, iso8601

I have a large amount of date/time fields that need to be changed in excel.  I need to subtract 2 hours from the current date/time format ISO 8601.

Ex:
2006-09-21 16:45:00 +0000  <----Changed to------>2006-09-21 14:45:00 +0000

I was able to parse the data into separate columns and subtract 2 hours using this formula: =B1+TIME(2,0,0) and then concentrate the columns back.

I ran into a problem when the time is 01:59:99 or less. It gives me #######

Anyone have a formula to subtract 2 hours from ISO 8601 format. Please and thank you.

Comment: Just add that value back to your date and it should display properly. Excel won't display negative times (when using the 1900 date system), but the actual value (fraction of a day) is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

This should help, if your original value is in Cell A2:

```
=IF(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,12,2))<2,LEFT(A2,8)&TEXT(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,9,2))-1,"00")&" "&TEXT(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,12,2)-2+24),"00")&RIGHT(A2,12),LEFT(A2,8)&TEXT(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,9,2)),"00")&" "&TEXT(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,12,2)-2),"00")&RIGHT(A2,12))
```

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Correct. The date would have to change as well which is where Im stumped.

Comment: Hi user3058374,
this formula should then help on your specific issue:
=IF(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,12,2))<2,LEFT(A2,8)&TEXT(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,9,2))-1,"00")&" "&TEXT(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,12,2)-2+24),"00")&RIGHT(A2,12),LEFT(A2,8)&TEXT(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,9,2)),"00")&" "&TEXT(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,12,2)-2),"00")&RIGHT(A2,12))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a single formula, you can use:

```
A1:  your_ISO_datetime
B1:  =LEFT(A1,19)-TIME(2,0,0)
   with custom format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss "+0000"
```

[image]